# Akka - use actorSelection with ask pattern

Tags: scala, akka

So, when sending a message using the ask pattern (`actor ? msg`), it creates a "[one-off actor](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.5/index.html#akka.pattern.package)" behind the scenes.

My question is - Is it possible to send this temporary actor a message using `actorSelection`?

For example, the following code works well:

```
object Test extends App {

  case class WrappedMsg(msg: String, replyTo: ActorRef)

  class Source(target: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    def receive = { case _ => } // doesn't matter

    implicit val execution = context.dispatcher
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)
    val middleware = context.actorOf(Props(new Middleware(target)))
    (middleware ? "Something").mapTo[String].onComplete {
      case Success(msg) => println("Success: " + msg)
      case Failure(err) => println("Failure: " + err)
    }
  }

  class Middleware(target: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case msg: String =>
        val wrappedMsg = WrappedMsg(replyTo = sender(), msg = msg)
        target ! wrappedMsg
    }
  }

  class Target extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case wrappedMsg: WrappedMsg => wrappedMsg.replyTo ! "Received"
    }
  }

  val system = ActorSystem()
  val target = system.actorOf(Props(new Target))
  val source = system.actorOf(Props(new Source(target)))

}
```

But, if I make the following changes, in order to use the actor url instead of ActorRef, it fails:

```
case class WrappedMsg(msg: String, replyTo: String)
...
val wrappedMsg = WrappedMsg(replyTo = sender().path.toSerializationFormat, msg = msg)
...
case wrappedMsg: WrappedMsg => context.actorSelection(wrappedMsg.replyTo) ! "Received"
```

Thanks

Comment: What does "it fails" mean?

Comment: The "Received" message doesn't reach to Source (through the temp actor).
In the first case, "Success" is printed and in the second case "Failure" is printed.

Comment: `sender().path.toSerializationFormat` returns `akka://default/temp/$a`, btw

Comment: Both versions of your code work for me.

Comment: @Zernike Really? I tried it again. I'm getting `Failure: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://default/user/$b/$a#-2124168879]] after [5000 ms]`.  What version of Akka do you use? (I use 2.3.6)

Comment: @AlonL http://prntscr.com/7uu3ph

Comment: Ok, with Akka 2.3.12 it works, with Akka 2.3.6 it doesn't. I'm posting this as an answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Zernike (see the comments in the question), we've found out that in Akka 2.3.12 it works well - the temporary actor is resolved using `actorSelection`. (The original code that caused the failure was tested in Akka 2.3.6)